# Using a javascript class method to reset the values of a previously submitted form

Tags: javascript, oop

I am attempting to use a class method to clear a form that may have been previously submitted using vanilla Javascript. While the functionality works outside of a class, inside has been a nightmare to figure out, and using `.reset()` returns the previously submitted values. Ideally I'd be able to call this methods inside of other methods to keep things DRY as clearing the form is used quite a lot.

The result of what I have below is no console errors, and otherwise expected functionality, just the previously submitted data still populating the form. Console logging the elements (`input`) in the `clearForm()` method returns the expected DOM element.

There seems to be some sort of knowledge gap on my part and I'd like to fill it.

Currently I have this for clearing:

```
[class and constructor]...
/* in my constructor this._form = document.querySelector(target); where target is a param 
   containing the target element's id or class */

       clearForm() {
            [...this._form.elements].forEach((input) => {
                if (input.type == "checkbox") {
                    input.checked = false
                    input.setAttribute("value", false);
                    return;
                }

                input.value = "";
                input.setAttribute("value", "");
            });
        }
```

And I put it to use in other methods such as:

```
       async populateForm(id) {
            try {
                await this.clearForm();
                [additional functionality]...
            } catch (e) {
              ...
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There's nothing asynchronous about that method, it doesn't return a promise. Do not `await` it.

Comment: Please post the full working code (with the function outside of the class) and the full not working code. The DOM does not work differently when used from within a class. There must be some other difference that causes the problem.

Comment: @Bergi you're right with the `await`, i removed that though the method it is inside is still async as after clearing it fetches API data asynchronously, after that it assigns the new dyanmic values to the data based on their names, kind of long winded functionality I need to refine but it does function without the clear data. The place where this is not working well is where I try to clear the form for new user input data as it retains the older values.